# Looping through a nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary set up that I'm trying to access but having trouble accessing the 'nextmo' part when the key is set to something my user decides (I've set to Feb in the example below). Ideally it should print 'Mar'

```
D = {'Jan': {'days': 31, 'nextmo': 'Feb', 'prevmo': 'Dec'},
 'Feb': {'days': 29, 'nextmo': 'Mar', 'prevmo': 'Jan'},
 'Mar': {'days': 31, 'nextmo': 'Apr', 'prevmo': 'Feb'},
 'Apr': {'days': 30, 'nextmo': 'May', 'prevmo': 'Mar'}, 
 'May': {'days': 31, 'nextmo': 'Jun', 'prevmo': 'Apr'},
 'Jun': {'days': 30, 'nextmo': 'Jul', 'prevmo': 'May'},
 'Jul': {'days': 31, 'nextmo': 'Aug', 'prevmo': 'Jun'},
 'Aug': {'days': 31, 'nextmo': 'Sep', 'prevmo': 'Jul'}, 
 'Sep': {'days': 30, 'nextmo': 'Oct', 'prevmo': 'Aug'},
 'Oct': {'days': 31, 'nextmo': 'Nov', 'prevmo': 'Sep'},
 'Nov': {'days': 30, 'nextmo': 'Dec', 'prevmo': 'Nov'},
 'Dec': {'days': 31, 'nextmo': 'Jan', 'prevmo': 'Jan'},}

bday_month_in = "Feb"

for k, v in D.items():
    if bday_month_in is dict:
       print(bday_month_in['nextmo'])
```

Comment: Don't know what you are doing exactly, but it looks a little bit over complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want the next month after `bda_month_in`, then this should work:

```
bday_month_in = 'Feb'
D[bday_month_in]['nextmo']  # 'Mar'
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually tried a variance of that but done D['bday_month_in']

Answer (score 1):

First, there is one major issue in your code:

```
if bday_month_in is dict:
    # [...]
```

Here, `bday_month_in` is a string (`"Feb"`), not a dictionary, so this `if` statement will never be true.

Now if you want to iterate over nested dictionnaries you can do that:

```
for (month, inner_dict) in D.items():                   
    print("Month: {}".format(month))
    for (key, value) in inner_dict.items():
        print("   key={}, value={}".format(key, value))
```

But it seems from your question that you don't even need to iterate over nested dictionnaries:

```
D['Feb']['nextmo']
```

Comment: Thanks for this! sure that will come in handy (: